# How to handle utf-8 non-breaking spaces in CSV

Tags: python, excel, csv, utf-8

In a Python script I am using `openpyxl` to read an XLSX file. I move some metadata around, and ultimately writing out a new CSV. When I open that CSV in Microsoft Excel, there are whitespaces in a certain metadata field that are being replaced with the following characters: `†¬`. Here is a before and after example…

Before (XLSX):

```
list of items
1.     apple
2.     orange
3.     banana
```

After (CSV as viewed in Excel):

```
list of items
1.¬†¬†¬†¬† apple
2.¬†¬†¬†¬† orange
3.¬†¬†¬†¬† banana
```

If I open the CSV in Google Sheets it renders just fine. If I preview it in Mac OS finder, it also looks fine. If I look at the CSV as plain text in Sublime Text it also looks fine. It is only Excel that renders these space characters in the strange fashion. Looking at the data in Sublime Text does seem to provide a hint… one would typically expect space characters to show a dot when you have selected them, so as to differentiate them from a tab whitespace. When I select these spaces however, the ones that Excel renders incorrectly do not show dots, and the one space it handles correctly does show a dot as expected.

[image]

Looking at that selection one might assume that the non-dotted whitespace is just a tab, but it is not, you can move the cursor four increments over, so it seems to be four whitespaces. After a lot of searching I finally found that I could just copy and paste these two different whitespaces into a UTF-8 encoder. This revealed that the correctly rendered space is `\x20` aka "space" and that the ones Excel struggles with are `\xc2\xa0` aka "no-break space".

I would like to preserve the original / source metadata as pristinely as possible, so I am not inclined to replace the non-breaking spaces with regular spaces, but should I be doing so in my Python? Is that unicode character liable to be incorrectly rendered by other tools? Is there something more nefarious going on here that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel assumes an encoding depending on the localization of Windows.  If the CSV isn't written in that encoding, you get [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).  Your file is written in UTF-8 encoding which isn't the localized default.  Write the CSV as UTF-8 w/ BOM and Excel will recognize the UTF-8 BOM signature and use UTF-8 to decode the file.  Python has the `'utf-8-sig'` encoding for that purpose.

Comment: For some reason I had been trying to add the encoding to the writer, but it turns out it goes in the initial "open" i.e. `finalcsv = open("metadata.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig")` worked like a charm!